# Correct way to declare and name a partial version of an interface

Tags: typescript, oop, naming-conventions

What would be the "right" way to declare the Book Interface in the following scenario, keeping in mind that we know the exact structure of the book object in both cases.
Let's say there is a Book interface:

```
export interface Book {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  year: number;
  authorId: string;
  pages: number;
  language: string;    
}
```

And an Author interface, that has a books property, array of "partial" book objects:

```
export interface Author {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  // How this book object should be declared?
  books: Array<{ id: string; title: string, year: number }>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "partial" you're referring to making any of the properties on `Book` optional you could use typescript's exported helper `Partial`:

```
export interface Author {
  ...
  books: Partial<Book>[]
}
```

if by "partial" you mean that it only includes *some* properties of `Book` and those properties should maintain their original type then you can use typescript's exported helper type `Pick`

```
export interface Author {
  ...
  books: Pick<Book, "id" | "title" | "year">[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to accomplish.

You can use the Partial keyword, `books: Partial<Book>[];`, or create another interface to contain `{ id: string; title: string, year: number }` of the Book interface.